# Common React Components across multiple apps

Tags: reactjs, git

We have 3 react apps. Some of the components being used in these apps are common for the 3 apps. We want to have a separate common git repo, where we can put the code for the common components and use those components in the 3 apps. Currently, we do have a repo for common components which is linked from the 3 apps like this in package.json:

`package-name username/repo#commit-id`

This arrangement poses some difficulties:

- For some reason, hooks don't work in the common repo even if we upgrade the react version.
- While developing locally, we change package.json to `package-name ../path`. Everytime we make a change locally in the common repo, the common repo has to be built again manually.

Overall, the process is not good. Many times it throws strange errors which are hard to solve.

Can you suggest an alternative way to accomplish the same?

Comment: When you say "Everytime we make a change locally, the common repo has to be built again manually." what are you "changing locally"? Are you changing the common repo or a project that uses that repo?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The common repo.

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason, hooks don't work in the common repo even if we upgrade the react version.

Treat the component package as its own project. It should have its own `package.json` that declares its dependencies.

It sounds like you are trying to develop the component package at the same time you develop the other projects that use them. Instead, you should develop the component package in its own environment. If you find problems or think of new features to add to the component package while you work on a project that uses it, create new issues for the component package project and work on them there.

The projects that use this component package should declare a specific version (either by a tag or a commit) which they use. Upgrading to a new version of the component package should follow the same process as upgrading versions of a 3rd party package, such as React itself.

Comment: Please answer this question where I explain the hooks problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651501/error-invalid-hook-call-while-using-common-components-across-apps