# Error: "Invalid hook call" while using common components across apps

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a common components React repo whose components are used in other React apps. In common components repo, if I use class based components or function based components without hooks, it works fine. As soon as I use hooks in this repo, the other repos which use these components starts giving the error: `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`
Here is how I use hooks:

```
 import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
 
 function Timeline() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return(<div>test{count}</div>)   
 }
```

How are the two apps linked? The main app has this in package.json (while working locally):

`"common-components": "../common_repo"`

I think the problem lies in package.json, even though both react and react-dom have the same version: 16.14.0 in both apps.

Here is the package.json for the common components repo:

```
{
  "name": "@something/something",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Common components",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.es.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.22",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "date-fns": "^1.28.5",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
    "match-sorter": "^6.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "react-axios": "^2.0.3",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.10.1",
    "react-datetime-picker": "^3.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "react-semantic-ui-datepickers": "^1.12.0",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-to-print": "^2.4.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "0.83.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "kx-build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-file index.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9009 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public",
    "build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && rollup -c"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16.14.0",
    "react-dom": ">=16.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.17",
    "@svgr/rollup": "^2.4.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.4",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-external-helpers": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "rollup": "^0.64.1",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^3.0.7",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^9.1.3",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^2.5.0",
    "rollup-plugin-sass": "^1.2.2",
    "rollup-plugin-url": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.3"
  }
}
```

This is the package.json of the app that uses the common components repo:

```
{
  "name": "@somename/somename",
  "homepage": ".",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "restricted"
  },
  "author": "Some Author",
  "dependencies": {
    "@blueprintjs/core": "^3.22.0",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.11",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.10",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.6.0",
    "@reach/router": "^1.2.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^23.2.1",
    "ajv": "^6.10.2",
    "ajv-keywords": "^3.4.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.580.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.8.1",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.0.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "common-components": "../common_repo",
    "loadsh": "0.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "material-table": "^1.67.0",
    "material-ui-pickers": "^2.2.4",
    "mixpanel": "^0.11.0",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.38.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.71",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^12.2.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.3",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.16.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^1.0.0",
    "react-individual-character-input-boxes": "^1.0.1-0",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^5.0.5",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.14",
    "react-material-ui-form-validator": "^2.0.9",
    "react-new-window": "^0.1.3",
    "react-pdf": "^4.1.0",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.3",
    "react-print-components": "^1.0.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-resizable": "^1.10.1",
    "react-rnd": "^10.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "react-semantic-ui-datepickers": "^2.0.0",
    "react-split-pane": "^0.1.82",
    "react-table": "^7.6.2",
    "react-tabs": "^3.1.1",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "react-to-print": "^2.3.2",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-form": "^8.2.6",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sass-watch": "^0.1.0",
    "semantic-ui-calendar-react": "^0.15.3",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.1",
    "validate.js": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "4.42.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "docker-build": "./dockertest.sh",
    "sass": "sass ./src/styleSheets/scss/index.scss:./src/styleSheets/css/index.css --style compressed"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I ran `npm ls react-dom` in both the repos. In common components repo I got this output:

```
+-- @storybook/addon-actions@5.3.21
| `-- @storybook/components@5.3.21
|   `-- react-dom@16.14.0  deduped
+-- @storybook/react@5.3.21
| `-- @storybook/core@5.3.21
|   `-- @storybook/ui@5.3.21
|     `-- react-dom@16.14.0  deduped
`-- react-dom@16.14.0
```

In the app that uses common components, I got this output:

```
`-- react-dom@16.14.0
```

When I ran `npm ls react` in both the repos, in the common components repo I got this output:

```
+-- @storybook/addon-actions@5.3.21
| +-- @storybook/api@5.3.21
| | `-- react@16.14.0  deduped
| +-- @storybook/components@5.3.21
| | `-- react@16.14.0  deduped
| `-- react@16.14.0  deduped
+-- @storybook/react@5.3.21
| `-- @storybook/core@5.3.21
|   `-- @storybook/ui@5.3.21
|     `-- react@16.14.0  deduped
`-- react@16.14.0
```

In the app that uses common components, I got this output:

```
`-- react@16.14.0
```